# Bash script to test file existence

Tags: bash

I'm trying to check if the filespaths written in a txt file (of user jane) are present in the system. This is the file list.txt:

```
001 jane /data/jane_profile_07272018.doc
002 kwood /data/kwood_profile_04022017.doc
003 pchow /data/pchow_profile_05152019.doc
004 janez /data/janez_profile_11042019.doc
005 jane /data/jane_pic_07282018.jpg
006 kwood /data/kwood_pic_04032017.jpg
007 pchow /data/pchow_pic_05162019.jpg
008 jane /data/jane_contact_07292018.csv
009 kwood /data/kwood_contact_04042017.csv
010 pchow /data/pchow_contact_05172019.csv
```

This is the script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$(grep ' jane ' ../data/list.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 3)
for i in $file
do
  i="~${i}"
  if (test -e $i); then echo "File exists"; else echo "File doesn't exist"; fi
done
```

I don't understand why the command

```
test -e ~/data/jane_profile_07272018.doc
```

is true, but when I write it like in the script above it returns false. Is it related to the way i'm adding the ~? Without it the command by itself returns false.

Comment: I think `~` only works from the bash command-line. Try $HOME instead?

Comment: `~` will work in scripts, but not if it's in quotes (as it is here). So try `i="${HOME}${i}"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `~` in front of `~/data/jane_profile_07272018.doc` is roughly equivalent to `$HOME/data/jane_profile_07272018.doc`. So instead of looking for the file under root `/`, it is looking for the file under your HOME directory.

You should do:

```sh
if [[ -e "$file" ]]; then
    echo "$file: exists"
else
    echo "file: does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: `while IFS= read -r f; do p="$HOME/$f"; if [ -e "$p" ]; then printf '%s exists\n' "$p"; fi; done < <(sed -n 's/^[[:digit:]]\+ jane //p' list.txt)`